# Rook and Pawn Endgames

Tags: endgame, rook-endgame

I want to learn more about rook and pawn endgames because they are very common. But it’s such a broad subject - where should I even begin?

For example, I do know of the Philidor and Lucena positions, but are there any other fundamental endgames positions I should know? Or should I take a different approach to getting started here?

Thanks so much!

Comment: This is an extremely broad topic, and depends a lot on how good you are. Have you read "100 endgames you must know" by Jesus de la Villa?

Comment: @NoseKnowsAll You took the words right out of my mouth, including recommending that book! (and the companion workbook)

Comment: I'll definitely have to pick that book up, I'm guessing Amazon would be my best option then? do you have any other recommendations for books?

Comment: Colton, there is that book, and a new companion workbook. Both are pretty inexpensive overall. In addition, Jeremy Silman's "Complete Endgame Course" is another good book that is designed for beginners on up. Again, it is pretty cheap too. Right now, all three books total are under $50, and that should be all you need covering the endgame for years.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [(practical) Endgame resources: What's next after josh waitzkin's series in chessmaster?](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/35641/practical-endgame-resources-whats-next-after-josh-waitzkins-series-in-chess)

Answer (score 2):

Before consulting a book, try reading the Wikipedia article on [rook and pawn endgames](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rook_and_pawn_versus_rook_endgame).

As you mention, it's a very broad topic.